# How I can add 'ErrorProvider1' to my function

Tags: vb.net

I've learned a lot from this beautiful website and still have a question I can not find an answer to him
How I can add 'ErrorProvider1' to my function
thes way it not working 
Is there any suggestions

```
Public Function checkif_nothing(ByVal frm As Form, controal_colection As Control.ControlCollection) As Boolean 'chick if no valu in text box an combobox in form 
        Dim msg As Boolean = True
        Dim ctrl As Control
        For Each ctrl In controal_colection
            If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox)) Then
                Dim txt As TextBox = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
                If txt.Text = "" Then
                    txt.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
                   frm.ErrorProvider1.SetError(txt, "Please Fill Textbox")
                    msg = False
                End If
            End If
            If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(ComboBox)) Then
                Dim comp As ComboBox = CType(ctrl, ComboBox)
                If comp.SelectedItem = Nothing Then
                    comp.BackColor = Color.LightYellow

                    frm.ErrorProvider1.SetError(comp, "Select one Value")
                    msg = False
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Return msg

    End Function
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour] as you agreed to when you joined.  `it not working` is a terrible problem description

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it not working". What _is_ happening? Are you getting errors?

Comment: when i write the line   frm.ErrorProvider1.SetError(    i get  red line under errorprovider1  and it say " ErrorProvider1 is not a member of 'form' "

Comment: And so it isnt - `Form` is the base class that all forms inherit. It doesnt include an ErrorProvider or any controls.  You passed your form `As Form` which casts it to the base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i pass the err to the function and that help me

```
 Public Function checkif_nothing(err As ErrorProvider, controal_colection As Control.ControlCollection) As Boolean 'chick if no valu in text box an combobox in form 
        Dim msg As Boolean = True
        Dim ctrl As Control
        For Each ctrl In controal_colection

            If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox)) Then
                Dim txt As TextBox = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
                If txt.Text = "" Then
                    txt.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
                    err.SetError(txt, "Please Fill Textbox")

                    msg = False
                End If
            End If
            If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(ComboBox)) Then
                Dim comp As ComboBox = CType(ctrl, ComboBox)
                If comp.SelectedItem = Nothing Then
                    comp.BackColor = Color.LightYellow

                    err.SetError(comp, "Select one Value")
                    msg = False
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Return msg

    End Function
```